# how to get the php error message in javascript with fetch

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, fetch

I try to get my customized php error message within the fetch promise in js. but it looks like the basic catch only gives me back the status text from the http response code.

my php is written in symfony

```
#[Route('/test', name:'test', methods: ['POST'])]
public function test(Request $req): Response
{
  return new JsonResponse(['error' => 'my Cusom Error'], 400);
}
```

javascript:

```
let btn = document.getElementById('myButton');
btn.addEventListener('click', function(event){
  const fd = new FormData(); // need it because want to send some files with it later
  fd.append('user', 'myUserName');

  fetch('/test', {method: 'POST', body: fd})
    .then((response) => {
      if(!response.ok){
        throw Error(response.statusText); 
        // how to catch the message returned form the server here?
        // the response object does not have this information
        // using response.error() returns a error that error is not function
        // response.error is undefined and has no information
        // a workaround is using the resposen.json().then((errorData) => {...}) inside here, but looks not fine for me.
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('data received', data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.log(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: Are you actually asking how to change the HTTP response code from PHP? Because all you're doing right now is just returning some JSON. The request will always appear to succeed as far as the browser is concerned.

Comment: @ADyson thats not correct. response.ok is false because php returns a 400 and not a 200

Comment: Sorry I missed you were using a symfony jsonresponse

Comment: Can't you just look in the network tab to find where the error message is?

Comment: the problem is solved. i did not know that i can throw it with await before

Comment: @ElTi-42 never add answers/solutions inside the question. Propose to add it in the selected answer or add an answer using the answer section

Comment: @gp_sflover, thanks, i was not confirm with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the body just like usual.

```
throw await response.json();
```

will work normally.

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for:

Answer (score 0):

My solution looks like this

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('#myButton');
btn.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const fd = new FormData();
  fd.append('user', 'myUserName');

  fetch('/test', {method: 'POST', body: fd}
    .then(async (response) => {
      if(!response.ok)
        throw await response.json();
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((data) => {
      console.log('success', data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    })
});
```

and it works now. big thanks to GoldenretriverYT